# How are the Top Cow comics series related to each other?

Tags: comics, top-cow-universe

Is there a good guide/chart explaining how all the series in Top Cow comics Universe are related to each other? (when I say "all", I mean the ones that are - somehow - related to "Witchblade" - I don't know if that's the entire Top Cow world or if there are series 100% separate from Witchblade/Artifacts world).

E.g., from my very brief knowledge, I know that:

- Witchblade, wielded by Sara Pezzini, is one of the Artifacts covered in Artifacts series
- Patience from Magdalena series appeared in Witchblade #62

However, I am looking good in-depth reference about all the assorted links - either conceptual, character-wise, and/or plot-happenings-wise - between those series.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, there is a Top Cow Bible. But I didn't read it so, I can't tell if explains everything. The "Aphrodite IX The Hidden Files #1" comicbook explains something about how are some events in the books connected and how they led to the future in which is that book(it has a short description of the 13 Artifacts also).

Comment: Is that a book/comic from the same creators, or a website from 3rd party?